# How to specify updates in WSUS

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, windows-update, wsus

I have WSUS on Windows server 2003 64 bit. I want to specify updates for my clients, for example some PCs I don't want them to update to Internet explore 8 and WSUS has downloaded and updated by itself and I don't want to go to one by by one to install it by hand so is it possible to tell WSUS that this PC do not install/update Internet explore or other updates?
Any advice would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can build [Computer Groups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939858%28WS.10%29.aspx) and allow Updates for [specific subgroups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939929%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: I have tried to prevent internet explore to install by itself but I didn't find it in WSUS could you please tell me what is the name of this update?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to prevent that Internet Explorer is installed at all or do you want to prevent that certain PCs get Security Updates for Internet Explorer?